# Find image inside a checkbox using jquery find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the src attribute of images inside checkboxes based on if they are checked or not. The checking if checked works but the `.attr("src")` is always undefined.

How do i get the img inside the checkbox ?

```
cboxes.each(function() {
  cb = $(this);
  cbImg = cb.find("img");

  if (cb.is(':checked')) {

    alert(cbImg.attr("src")); //returns undefined

    cbImg.attr("src", "css/img/checkbox_fylld.png");
  } else {

    cbImg.attr("src", "css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png");
  }
});
```

And the HTML

```
<ul class="nav-justified">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="0">
      <img class="ageSelectImg" src="css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png" />
      <br />0-2år</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="2">
      <img class="ageSelectImg" src="css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png" />
      <br />2-10 år</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="10">
      <img class="ageSelectImg" src="css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png" />
      <br />10+ år</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how do you put an image inside a checkbox? put your complete code please

Comment: @Mojtaba Ofcourse. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're not closing the input tag

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Thanks!

Comment: There is no closing tag for input tags.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ageSelect').each(function() { 
        cb = $(this);
        cbImg = cb.next("img");
        if (cb.attr('selected')) {
            alert(cbImg.attr("src"));//returns undefined
             cbImg.attr("src", "css/img/checkbox_fylld.png");
        } else {
            cbImg.attr("src", "css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png");
        }
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-justified">
                        <li><label><input class="ageSelect" type="radio" selected id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="0"> <img class="ageSelectImg" src="css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png" /><br />0-2år </label></li>
                        <li><label><input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="2"> <img class="ageSelectImg" src="css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png" /><br />2-10 år</label></li>
                        <li><label><input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="10"><img class="ageSelectImg" src="css/img/checkbox_ofylld.png" /><br />10+ år</label></li>
                    </ul>
```

You do not have any checkboxes. They are radio buttons.

However, here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your images are not *inside* your checkboxes. Checkbox inputs are self-closing tags (also you should terminate them with `/>`).

Instead of `.find("img")` use `.next("img")`.

One last important thing : you need to wrap your image handling inside an event listener:

```
$("input[name=\"timeSpan\"").on("change", function() {...});
```

so the code is executed every time a change is made to the radio input.

```js
$("input[name=\"timeSpan\"").on("change", function() {

  $("input[name=\"timeSpan\"").each(function() {

    var cbImg = $(this).next("img");

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) cbImg.attr("src", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/8/c/0/1197121244407718078webmichl_powerbutton_2_states_%28_on_off_%29_1.svg.med.png");

    else cbImg.attr("src", "https://www.windmobile.ca/images/default-source/icons/icons---koray/power-on-off.jpg");
  });
});
```

```css
.ageSelectImg {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-justified">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="0" />
      <img class="ageSelectImg" src="https://www.windmobile.ca/images/default-source/icons/icons---koray/power-on-off.jpg" />
      <br />0-2år</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="2" />
      <img class="ageSelectImg" src="https://www.windmobile.ca/images/default-source/icons/icons---koray/power-on-off.jpg" />
      <br />2-10 år</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="ageSelect" type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="10" />
      <img class="ageSelectImg" src="https://www.windmobile.ca/images/default-source/icons/icons---koray/power-on-off.jpg" />
      <br />10+ år</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```